# Problem with restructuring scripting dictionary code to not remove similar data

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, scripting

I have a scripting dictionary code which removes data which is similar. The code removes data which are almost duplicates which I don't want.

I have data in this form:

```
USA Test Green
USA Test Blue
India Test Red
India Test White
```

I want the data to be converted into this form

```
USA: 
Test Green
Test Blue
India: 
Test Red
Test White
```

However, I get these results with my current code

```
USA: 
Test Green
Test Blue
India: 
Test Red

'<---- missing last observation
```

I'm almost sure that this happens because I have

```
If Not InStr(1, countrydict(country), data) > 0
```

In my code and I've tried to remove several parts of my code but I have not been able to get it to work.

My code is the following

```
With ActiveSheet
    For iter = 2 To lastrow
        country = Trim(.Cells(iter, 1).Value)
        data = Trim(.Cells(iter, 2).Value)
       If countrydict.Exists(country) Then
        If Not InStr(1, countrydict(country), data) > 0 Then ' <---- This is most likely where I have gone wrong
        countrydict(country) = countrydict(country) & "|" & data ' an array would work but we can instr a string
        End If
        Else
            countrydict.Add country, data
        End If
    Next
    iter = 2
    For Each key In countrydict
        .Cells(iter, 1).Value = key & ":"
        .Cells(iter, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 219, 235)
        .Cells(iter, 1).Font.Size = 11
        .Cells(iter, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Arial"
        .Cells(iter, 1).Font.Bold = True
        iter = iter + 1
        For diter = 0 To UBound(Split(countrydict(key), "|"))
            .Cells(iter, 1).Value = Split(countrydict(key), "|")(diter)
            .Cells(iter, 1).Font.Size = 9
            .Cells(iter, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Arial"
            iter = iter + 1
        Next
    Next
    .Columns("B").Clear
End With
```

As always help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check why the last row is not handled? Is `lastrow` set correctly?

Comment: What is "almost similar" which rule or algorithm is behind that? What should your code consider as "almost" similar? You need to be very precise about that because "almost" is not defined, so there must be a strict rule about what "almost" means. For example "almost" can mean maximum 1 character is different or maximum 5 characters are different. So what is the rule that you are planning to use? • Note that knowing this rule is neceessary to write a code for what you ask for. If you don't know that rule you cannot write a code.

Comment: @FunThomas you were right, the only problem was that the variable lastrow was not set right. Thx a lot for pointing it out. It's funny how I've spent hours trying to solve this when it was just that simple :P

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for pointing it out. The problem was just that the lastrow variable was not set right.